# POST XML file with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm getting:

```
<error>You have an error in your XML syntax...
```

when I run this python script I just wrote (I'm a newbie)

```
import requests

xml = """xxx.xml"""

headers = {'Content-Type':'text/xml'}

r = requests.post('https://example.com/serverxml.asp', data=xml)

print (r.content);
```

Here is the content of the xxx.xml

```
<xml>
<API>4.0</API>
<action>login</action>
<password>xxxx</password>
<license_number>xxxxx</license_number>
<username>xxx@xyz.com</username>
<training>1</training>
</xml>
```

I know that the xml is valid because I use the same xml for a perl script and the contents are being printed back.

Any help will greatly appreciated as I am very new to python.

Comment: You are not actually reading in the file. AFAIK the parameter `data` expects the actual contents of your XML file, not its name

Comment: Found the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Session.post) *data -- (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the Request.* So you need to either parse the XML file into something you can attach or open the file and pass that object to the parameter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to give the XML data from a file to `requests.post`. But, this function will not open a file for you. It expects you to pass a file object to it, not a file name. You need to open the file before you call requests.post.

Try this:

```
import requests

# Set the name of the XML file.
xml_file = "xxx.xml"

headers = {'Content-Type':'text/xml'}

# Open the XML file.
with open(xml_file) as xml:
    # Give the object representing the XML file to requests.post.
    r = requests.post('https://example.com/serverxml.asp', data=xml, headers=headers)

print (r.content);
```

Comment: `headers` is unused here, as far as I can see. It is defined and not sent in the `POST` call. You can send both: `requests.post('<address>', headers=headers, data=xml)`
I checked this was true. I didn't get an error when not including it, but I think I'm seeing faster results with it... anyway, if just defining it and not passing it does something magical in Python that I don't know about that wouldn't surprise me. This answer did help me get further. There's my code review :)
I see the OP defined and didn't use it either.