# Performing a XML-Request against Czech Trade Licensing Register(RŽP) in Python

Tags: python, xml, post, python-requests

I need to create a funcion that will send xml with post request and receives it back in python.
On the [official site](https://www.rzp.cz/docs/RZP02_XML_28.pdf) (only available in Czech) there is only this little code of html form:

```
<form name="frmdata" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
   action="http://www.rzp.cz/cgi-bin/aps_cacheWEB.sh">
      <input type="hidden" name="VSS_SERV" value="ZVWSBJXML">
      <input type="file" name="filename">
      <input type="submit" name="x" value="ODESLI">
</form>
```

So I am trying to convert it like this to python, for automatization, but it is not working:

```
headers = {'Content-Type':'text/xml'}
url = 'http://www.rzp.cz/cgi-bin/aps_cacheWEB.sh'

with open('dotaz1.txt') as xml:
    myobj = {   'VSS_SERV': 'ZVWSBJXML',
                'X': 'ODESLI',
                'file': xml,
             }

    x = requests.post(url, data = myobj, headers=headers)
```

Does somebody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"?

Comment: Why do you pass a file pointer instead of a fileName ?

Comment: @mzjn That I get simple messege, that something went wrong, no idea what.

Comment: You have this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759981/python-trying-to-post-form-using-requests) with different possibilities

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : Trying to POST form using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759981/python-trying-to-post-form-using-requests)

Comment: @Ptit Xav to a reference to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140412/post-xml-file-with-requests

Comment: @PtitXav unfortunetlly no

Comment: In the form you do not send xml file contents but only a filename (may be I am wrong). So why do you try to read a file in the python code ? I would suggest to replace “file: xml “ by ‘fileName’: ‘dataz1.xml’

Comment: @PtitXav input is type of file, so you are sending it. But in html file, when I removed enctype from parameters it wont work, so meabz I need to define encryption on post request? But I cant find how anywhere.

Comment: Found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) about encryp. It seems you have to set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got the answer. I got some inspiration from this post, where there is a implementation for C# : [Make POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52806100/make-post-request)

As for python, trick was in sending it as a file, as it wont accept another format. Also the **text** variable in my code needs to be is shown format. You cant displace text from top or there will be error.

Code:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.rzp.cz/cgi-bin/aps_cacheWEB.sh'

text = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VerejnyWebDotaz xmlns="urn:cz:isvs:rzp:schemas:VerejnaCast:v1" version="2.8">
   <Kriteria>
     <IdentifikacniCislo>75848899</IdentifikacniCislo>
     <PlatnostZaznamu>0</PlatnostZaznamu>
   </Kriteria>
</VerejnyWebDotaz>
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
with open('query.xml', 'r+') as xml:
    xml.truncate(0)
    xml.write(text)
    xml.seek(0)
    request_data = {
        'VSS_SERV': 'ZVWSBJXML',
    }

    response = requests.post(url, data=request_data, files={'filename' : xml})
    print(f"status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(f"response:\n{response.text}")
```

To use it for automatization, all you need to do is to dynamiclly change ID of subject (IdentifikacniCislo)

Answer (score 1):

I got a valid response with the following code:

```py
import requests

url = 'http://www.rzp.cz/cgi-bin/aps_cacheWEB.sh'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('query.xml') as xml:
        request_data = {
            'VSS_SERV': 'ZVWSBJXML',
            'filenameList': xml
        }

        response = requests.post(url, data=request_data)
        print(f"status code: {response.status_code}")
        print(f"response:\n{response.text}")
```

*Please note:* The parameter `filenameList` differs from the official API documentation. However, using the described value of `filename` led to this very specific response from the server:

> Multiple definitions of filename encountered in input.
> If you're trying to do this intentionally (such as with select),
> the variable must have a "List" suffix.

I changed the request accordingly and got a valid XML response.
Further note that I do *not* set an explicit HTTP  handler but rather let the requests module pick the appropriate headers. It seems that this works fine - as long as you use `filenameList`. There are mentions about this issue on the internet. Just google for  the quoted error message and you will find a couple of results. It seems that by chosing *exactly* the correct HTTP headers you can also provide the `filename` attribute.

I found some help in this github repository: https://github.com/f4z4onZH27/rzp

I cannot resist resist but to quote from its readme:

> So, here we are, fixing government’s and major vendor’s incompetency.